# How to load a rack diagram from excel database

Tags: excel, visio

In organization chart...every shape can be linked to excel row of data 
(excel serves as a database for the chart which data can be edited from excel)

I'd like to load a rack diagram with servers according to my excel database.

1. I will move the servers in the rack and excel will be updated with the new location of the servers
2. I will update the servers ip location etc in excel and visio will display the updated information.

is it possible? how?

Comment: It's possible yes see http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/visio-help/create-a-rack-diagram-HP001211095.aspx

Comment: this link may also interest you http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/visio-help/show-ip-addresses-and-other-information-on-your-visio-network-diagrams-HA010151543.aspx

Comment: Thanks, I've found the first one myself...and it was half way: I can export the data and even load this as data but autolink to shapes ...select the right object (server, rack etc) does not work for me... thanks for the help